# Why Does a UIViewController With a Child View Controller Sometimes Return children[0].isEmpty = true?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, delegation

This problem came up when I was trying to pass updatedInfo from a parent UIViewController to an embedded/child UIViewController using `self.children[0].currentInfo = updatedInfo`. As it turned out, inside an "ordinary" function in the parent view controller, this worked fine. But from inside a delegate function in the parent view controller, it crashed the program. Apparently, sometimes – but not always – `self.children.isEmpty = true` inside delegate functions.

Without knowing the reason for this, I don't know how I could reliably use `self.children` to pass information. But I don't want to just avoid using it because I don't understand it. Any insights would be appreciated.

Since my app introduced too many complicating factors, I decided to examine the problem by creating a very simple "toy" app. Here's what I have (the code is below the screenshot of the storyboard):

[image]

In the MainViewController file, there's

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController, InfoDelegate {

    var text = "Text from MainViewController"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        printString("Text from MainViewController's viewDidLoad")
    }

    // Ordinary func
    func printString(_ string: String) {
        print(string)
        print("In printString, self.children.isEmpty is \(self.children.isEmpty)")
    }

    // Delegate func
    func messageString(_ string: String) {
        print(string)
        print("In messageString, self.children.isEmpty is \(self.children.isEmpty)")
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if let textViewController = segue.destination as? TextViewController {
            textViewController.text = text
            textViewController.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

And in TextViewController, there's

```
import UIKit

protocol InfoDelegate: AnyObject { func messageString(_ string: String) }

class TextViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    var text = "Text from TextViewController"
    weak var delegate: InfoDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textView.text = text
        delegate?.messageString("Text from TextViewController's InfoDelegate")
    }
}
```

Comment: `children` array will never be empty if you correctly followed vc containment

Comment: @Sh_Khan, I don't know what you're referring to by "vc containment." Did I not do so? And if so, how?

Comment: it refers to adding childs to a vc either programmatically or by containerView in IB

Comment: As the screenshot shows, the child vc was added by containerView in IB. So presumably I followed vc containment, then. Nevertheless, the `children` array was empty. Am I missing something?

Comment: is it empty in `viewDidLoad` ??

Comment: @Sh_Khan, no, it's not.

Comment: then assign the values there as i said in answer

Answer (score 0):

In `viewDidLoad` of `MainViewController`

```
if let child = self.children.first as? TextViewController { 
  child.text = text 
  child.delegate = self
}
else {
  print("problem setting the child ",self.children.count)
}
```

Comment: adding textViewController.loadViewIfNeeded() seems to have stopped the execution of the delegate function. Before inserting it, the output was
`Text from TextViewController's InfoDelegate
In messageString, self.children.isEmpty is true
Text from MainViewController's viewDidLoad
In printString, self.children.isEmpty is false'
Now it's just
`Text from MainViewController's viewDidLoad
In printString, self.children.isEmpty is false`

Comment: Adding that code to `viewDidLoad` of `MainViewController` didn't eliminate the problem. The print command in the delegate function still produces `In messageString, self.children.isEmpty is true`.

Comment: the children array gets it's assignment after `childs'viewDidLoad`  ==> `override var children:[UIViewController] { didSet {  } }` and trace when it's assigned

Answer (score 0):

The `prepare(for:sender:)` method gets called before the destination view controller's views have been loaded. It is probably also called before the child view controller is installed into the parent's `children` array. (I haven't tested this, but it makes sense. `prepare(for:sender:)` is called right after the destination is created, to give you a chance to do early setup.)

I suggest adding a didSet to your child's `delegate` property and testing this. Add a test `amIAChildYet` method to your delegate protocol and call it in the child view controller's delegate property's didSet() method to see the order in which things are set up.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to implement your advice. Your first paragraph suggests that things should have worked right, given my setup. But, of course, we know they didn't. About your specific suggestion to add a didSet, I don't know where I should put what. I'm still learning OOP, and since I'm not a professional programmer, I also sometimes forget what I haven't used in a while.